# Transparent gap within navigation bar

Tags: html, css, background, transparency

I am trying to make it so that there is a gap (but without setting the color to the same as the background) on the navigation bar where the current selected tab is...

To explain in more detail, I need to make the "My Page" tab (current selected tab) a transparent tab however it needs to display the background color instead of the navigation bar's color which is behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add one empty element for this to work.  Make sure that none of the ancestors to your nav element have a background other than the one you want to show through to your tab.

http://tinker.io/a5458

```
body {
    background: #F58B73;
}

.nav-links {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* could use `white-space: pre` instead */
}

.nav-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: #231F20;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.spacer {
    background: #231F20;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.nav-button-selected {
    background: transparent;
}

        <div class="nav-links pull-right">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="#" class="nav-button nav-button-selected">Who I am</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-button">What I do</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-button">How to contact me</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'm glad I didn't sound too stupid... Hopefully it was a good question. Ignore my previous comment - I've got it all working! Thanks a lot.